# ¿Es recomendable usar las ID en las URLs amigables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna regla que guste más a ojos de Google. Las URLs amigables que utilizo incluyen el ID de lo que quiero "cargar" en la página. Por ejemplo:

```
http://www.unawebcualquiera.mx/bocadillos/13/bocadillo-con-jamon/
```

Mi duda es que he visto varias webs que no usan estas ID en las URLs. En ese caso entiendo que buscan a través del texto, es decir, por `bocadillo con jamon`. Pero me surge una duda que no consigo resolver.

Si en la base de datos el título es `bocadillo con jamón`, no te va a encontrar nada (por el acento). No se me ocurre cómo trabajan este tipo de URLs amigables. Podría hacer que la URL fuese:

```
http://www.unawebcualquiera.mx/bocadillos/13/bocadillo-con-jam&oacute;n/
```

Pero evidentemente al hacer esto, aunque después podría limpiar el texto y buscar correctamente en la base de datos, entiendo que es una chapuza en cuanto a URLs amigables se refiere. ¿Afecta en algo usar IDs en la URL en cuanto a posicionamiento o comprensión por parte del robot de Google?

Comment: Una opción sería añadir una *columna* nueva con tus *URL amigables* (`bocadillo-con-jamon`), que sea `unique`, así te podría servir como *identificador*, y te evitas usar el `id`. Ante el usuario queda mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los acentos no son un problema. Los recibís codificados para URL ([RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html)) y se obtienen:

- Con [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) o [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php), PHP los entrega decodificados (por ejemplo, convierte a `%C3%B3` en `ó`). No es necesario hacer nada.

Pero si los obtenés directamente de la URL:

- [**urldecode()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) cuando lo recibiste de una cadena de búsqueda.
  `http://url.com/articulo.php?titulo=bocadillo-con-jam%C3%B3n`
- [**rawurldecode()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rawurldecode.php) cuando es parte de la ruta.
  `http://url.com/bocadillo-con-jam%C3%B3n`

```php
echo urldecode('bocadillo-con-jam%C3%B3n');
```

```
bocadillo-con-jamón
```

**¿El título como identificador?**

El tema importante acá es mantener un único nombre. Por ejemplo,

- ¿Estás seguro que no vas a cambiar jamás el nombre? ¿que ese nombre va a servir como identificador único de tu artículo?
- O si cambiara, ¿tenés ganas de generar todo el código para redireccionar de `bocadillo-con-jamón` a `bocadillo-con-queso`?
- Y ¿estás dispuesto a validar que ningún otro artículo se va a llamar `bocadillo-con-jamón`?

Por esos motivos es más práctico con ids.

Si aún estás interesado en usar al nombre del artículo como identificador principal, para generar la URL desde el texto con acentos (la inversa), [**rawurlencode()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rawurlencode.php):

```php
echo rawurlencode('http://web.com/bocadillo-con-jamón');
```

```
http://web.com/bocadillo-con-jam%C3%B3n
```

**Google no toma a un id en contra del SEO**.

> `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134309/es-recomendable-usar-las-id-en-las-urls-amigables`

Fijate la URL en la que estamos. Te aseguro que a SO no le va mal en los resultados de Google.

**¿Y el .htaccess?**

Sólo es cuestión de agregar los caracteres en tu regla, incluyendo a los acentos y la ñ, por ejemplo:

```python
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-záéíóúüñ]+)/?$ articulo.php?titulo=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Comment: Pues me ha servido de mucho tu contestación porque no conocía esos métodos. La pregunta era más por curiosidad puesto que se me hace más cómodo usar ID. Principalmente porque no puedo garantizar que el título del artículo sea el mismo que cuando lo publiqué (no sería lap rimera vez que me equivoco y lo escribo mal). Además, creo que si recojo la información a través de la URL con la ID, si el día de mañana lo cambio de categoría (aunque esto depende de la web) no tendré problemas en que la gente siga accediendo desde la URL antigua.

Comment: @JetLagFox Claro, personalmente usaría ids, dejando el nombre sólo para que la URL se vea mejor al leerla y tenga algo de info sobre qué trata, tal cual estás haciendo ahora, y tal cual hace SO... Fijate que si probás ir a https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134309/bla-bla-bla también te lleva a esta pregunta. Quise exponer las 2 alternativas en mi respuesta: las 2 son posibles y válidas, depende de cada uno elegir cuál.

Answer (score 1):

Mira cuando guardas URL en una base de datos, van a quedar cifradas algunas cosas como son los espacios, las Ñ  y otros caracteres especiales entonces, desde el php vas a enviar el registro de la URL con un encode y cuando hagas las consultas vas usar el Decode para que no te quede http://www.unawebcualquiera.mx/bocadillos/13/bocadillo%20con%20jam&oacute

Answer (score 1):

A la hora de trabajar con una id en la url debes tener cuidado con como la estás restringiendo, ya que un usuario podría cambiar la id en la url y ver un registro de otro usuario que quizá no deberia ver.

*Pan-con-jamon* o mejor dicho los slug's, se suelen crear en un nuevo campo dentro de la base de datos, en la respectiva tabla. Este slug no es más que es un string, si quieres utilizar el slug como id para una url asegúrate que este campo sea unique en la base de datos y que así que no se repita.

A la hora de guardar el slug en la base de datos puedes aplicar una modificación al string, quitar los acentos y posteriormente guardarlos, generalmente se suelen quitar ya que si quieres una pagina visible para todo el mundo en otros idiomas el acento no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque tu pregunta es mas de un foro que de stackoverflow(ver las normas de uso) te dire que no es mas recomendable ni menos recomendable, todo depende de lo que definas como critero de busqueda en tu base de datos, usar el ID es tan bueno como usar el slug, en cualquier caso nada se debe repetir, un ejemplo:

Articulo de mi web
ID 13
slug articulo-de-mi-web

```
http://unawebcualquiera.com/13/articulo-de-mi-web
http://unawebcualquiera.com/articulo-de-mi-web
```

cualquier opción es buena y no es mejor ni peor
y mi consejo es que te crees un método que te genere un slug correcto, aqui te dejo uno

```
public function getSlug($cadena, $separador = '-')
{

    $slug = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $cadena);
    $slug = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $slug);
    $slug = strtolower(trim($slug, $separador));
    $slug = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $separador, $slug);
    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Esa función está eliminando acentos